# Phoenix 1.2 - broadcast_from clarifications needed

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'm following along the book from PragProg "Programming Phoenix" and I'm currently on the chapters about Phoenix's channels.

At some point there's an example about setting up a simple channel with one topic and handling in/out messages between the client and server. No fancy stuff, everything worked as advertised.

Then I started investigating Phoenix.Channel's API and found "broadcast_from" function.

Doing a bit of research it was clear to me that using "broadcast_from" (from the channel) would have sent the message to all connected clients but the one whose message I was currently handling.

My current code is

```
defmodule Rumbl.VideoChannel do
   use Rumbl.Web, :channel

   def join("videos:" <> video_id, _params, socket) do
     :timer.send_interval(5000, :ping)
   {:ok, %{status: "successful join"}, assign(socket, :video_id, String.to_integer(video_id))}

   end

   def handle_info(:ping, socket) do
     count = socket.assigns[:count] || 1
     #push socket, "ping", %{count: count}
     broadcast_from! socket, "test", %{id: 1, status: :critical}
     {:noreply, assign(socket, :count, count + 1)}
   end

 end
```

I expected that, upon client's connection, the client would not receive
the "test" messages. And that was, indeed, the outcome. Until I opened another browser window and connected to the channel. At that point
both windows started receiving the "test" messages. It also happened if the second window was opened from another device (such as an iPhone).

Is that the normal behaviour or is it me misusing/misunderstanding the documentation?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's the normal behaviour. From the [broadcast_from](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html#broadcast_from/3) docu:

> The channel that owns the socket will not receive the published message.

It's a bit confusing. As I understand the docu, when you open another window, `join` creates another socket and therefore another pid from which you receive the test message in your first window. With one window you will see no test message. With two windows you will see the test messages each from the other pid of the two sockets.